# I want to overlap a div so when its button is clicked it becomes visible despite being first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The divs are off screen and comes in when a word is clicked. However if I click the last sequenced word first, then click the first sequenced word, I can't see the info from the first div. Whatever word I click I want to be able to see its respected div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#div1").click(function() {
      $(".contentdiv").css("left","-1400px");
      $("#experiment").animate({"left": "600px"}, 1000);
  });

  $("#div2").click(function() {
      $("contentdiv2").css("left","2000px");
      $("#experiment1").animate({"left": "600px"}, 1000);
  });

  $("#div3").click(function() {
      $(".contentdiv").css("left","-1400px");
      $("#experiment2").animate({"left": "600px"}, 1000);
  });

  $("#div4").click(function() {
      $(".contentdiv2").css("left","2000px");
      $("#experiment3").animate({"left": "600px"}, 1000);
  });

  $("#div5").click(function() {
      $(".contentdiv").css("left","-1400px");
      $("#experiment4").animate({"left": "600px"}, 1000);
  });

  $("#div6").click(function() {
      $(".contentdiv2").css("left","2000px");
      $("#experiment5").animate({"left": "600px"}, 1000);
  });

  $("#div7").click(function() {
      $(".contentdiv").css("left","-1800px");
      $("#experiment6").animate({"left": "600px"}, 1000);
  });

  $("#div8").click(function() {
      $(".contentdiv2").css("left","2000px");
      $("#experiment7").animate({"left": "600px"}, 1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: better to make a demo .. cause your code may be simplified more than that

Comment: What do you mean better to make a demo?

Comment: use a site like codepen, jsfiddle, jsbin or plunkr and copy your code to illustrate your problem